# Makefile doesn't detect rules

Tags: c, makefile

For my project a try to create a makefile for compil my project, but its first time i have a tree of folder.
I want to compile that:

```
makefile
main.c
src
   folder1
      code1.c
      code2.c
   folder2
      code3.c
      code4.c
   folder3
      code5.c
      code6.c
obj
   folder1
      code1.o
      code2.o
   folder2
      code3.o
      code4.o
   folder3
      code5.o
      code6.o
```

and my makefile is like

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -lncursesw -lm -lpthread
CC=gcc 
OBJS=obj
EXE=SimulateurCompile
INCLUDE=AllInclude.h

SRC_FOLDER:=$(wildcard src/*)
SRC_FOLDER:=$(SRC_FOLDER:src/%=obj/%)

SRC=$(wildcard src/*/*.c) main.c
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))
OBJS:=$(OBJS:src/%=obj/%)


%.o: %.c
    @echo "PASSAGE"
    ACompiler:=$($<:$(OBJS)%=src%)
    @echo $(ACompiler)
    @mkdir -p $(SRC_FOLDER)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c -g $(ACompiler) $(CFLAGS)

all:$(OBJS)
    gcc  $(SRC) -c -g -o $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS)
    @echo "Passage dans all\n"
    gcc -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDE)
```

But the makefile doesn't detect the rule for create .o
Someone know why and how can i create a makefile for my tree of file ?

Sorry for my english
Thank for read me :D

Comment: You did take care about the tabs instead of blanks, didn't you?

Comment: `%.o: %.c:` works with files in the current working directory. It knows nothing about `src` or `folder1` or `SRC_FOLDER` or any such thing.

Comment: Also you can't have `-o $(OBJS)`; your recipes should show how to compile one file at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```mk
SRCS:=$(wildcard src/*/*.c)
OBJS:=$(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(ALL_SRCS))

# Dump the above to make sure there weren't any errors so far:
$(info SRCS = $(SRCS))
$(info OBJS = $(OBJS))
$(info INCLUDES = $(INCLUDES))


obj/%.o : src/%.c $(INCLUDES)
        @echo "building $< -> $@"
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(CC) -o $@ -c -g $< $(CFLAGS) $(patsubst %,-I %,$(dir $(INCLUDES)))

all:$(OBJS)
        @echo "building $@"
        $(CC) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `ACompiler` in your example, but it wouldn't work -- you can't set a variable in one recipe line, and read it in the next (plus you're using `:=` to assign the variable which is not legal bash syntax).   I think you're trying to figure out `$(dir $<)` -- the directory of the source file.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Make has built-in recipes for building .o from .c and executable from object files. This line is enough for doing mostly what you want:

```
SimulateurCompile: $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard src/*/*))
```

This will put .o-files next to source files. I'd sooner recommend using something other than Make than messing with object folders, like Meson or SCons.

The built-in recipes uses variables you can set like CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS. See documentation for details on the built-in recipes.