# Makefile wildcard target expansion

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm a fairly new user of GNU Make. I want to get a list of Golang files and build each one of them using Make.

I want to create a target that will receive the apt Go file as a param.
In the snippet I've written the control of the program never reaches the %.go target.

Here is a snippet of a file.

```
EXECUTABLES := $(wildcard cmd/*/*/*.go)

%.go:
    echo "Build the go file"

build: $(EXECUTABLES)
    echo $<
```

Output:

```
echo cmd/abc/handler/main.go
cmd/abc/handler/main.go
```

I modified the script to this but I'm facing the same issue. Also tried replacing *%.go* with **.go* and  with *cmd/abc/handler/main.go*

Here is one of the variants mentioned above.

```
%.go:
    echo "Hello world"

build: $(wildcard cmd/*/*/*.go)
    echo $<
```

Anything I might be missing here?

Comment: not sure if this reply to your question but i believe u can find all u need here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/64860719/14436359

Comment: Hold on... *"I want to get a list of Golang files and build each one of them using Make."* If the Golang file already exists, then Make sees no reason to build it. Do you want to *rebuild* each Golang file that already exists?

Comment: @Hikachu Thank you, it is a good template that can be used.

Comment: @Beta, No, I didn't want to trigger a rebuild, I was thinking about it incorrectly.
I wanted a pattern to trigger a target but now I realize that the targets would be files that need to be built and the list of go files would be the pre-requisites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rule that tells make how to build a `.go` file.  But, you already *HAVE* a `.go` file.  Make doesn't have to build it, it's a source file that you wrote.  That rule has no prerequisites, so as far as make is concerned if the file exists, it's up to date (it doesn't depend on any other file).

So, when you ask make to build that file make looks and says "this file exists already, and it doesn't depend on anything, so the thing you asked me to do is already done and I don't need to run any commands".

When you write a makefile you have to think of it from the *end* first back to the beginning.  What is the thing you want to end up with?  That is the first target you write.  Then what files are used as inputs to that final thing?  Those are the prerequisites of that target.  And what commands are needed to create the target from the prerequisites?  That is the recipe.

Then once you have that, you think about those prerequisites, considering *them* as targets.  What prerequisites do *they* have?  And what commands do you need to turn *those* prerequisites into *that* target?

And you keep going backwards like that until you come to a place where all the prerequisites are original source files that can't be built from anything, then you're done.